# I have a start_date and end_date in my db table, how do I return all records where current date falls between those 2 values?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to see if a contract is currently active, so I need to check if the current date lies between the contract start date and end date.

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
```

Comment: I wanted to add more but this "guided" posting is horrible, it's impossible to type a post when the screen is jumping all over the place.

Comment: you can add current date in the model as well.

Comment: What if the contract has only one of the dates or has neither `start_date` nor `end_date`. You allow null values for both. Is a contract active if it has no value for both dates?

Comment: The null values are part of some testing I did and are part of old design, they won't be allowed later on. All contracts must have a start_date, permanent contracts that would not have an end_date will get an auto generated one far in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work to get the contracts where the start date is before or is today and the end date is after or is today.

lte == lower then or equal

gte == greater then or equal

```
from django.utils import timezone

date_today = timezone.now().date()    
active_contract = Contract.objects.filter(start_date__lte=date_today, end_date__gte=date_today)
```

Comment: This works, but only seems to return the first result.

Comment: It should work for all matching results. I cannot see the data so i cannot verify the dates.

Comment: How would you call the results in the template?

Comment: Nvm, suddenly it works without having done nothing to it :/ Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
Contract.objects.filter(start_date__lte=today, end_date__gte=today)
```